# Associated databases with elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch

Just installed the elasticsearch gem and been configuring it.

I got the search working on the right model. However on the view I also include data from an associated database model called **company** and it gives me this error:

```
undefined method `company' for #<Elasticsearch::Model::Response::Result:0x000001032d67d0>
```

If I try to remove everything related to that associated database in the view, the search works perfectly. So it's just the problem of figuring this out.

My model for **application.rb** looks like this:

```
require 'elasticsearch/model'
class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :answers
include Elasticsearch::Model
include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks
....
```

my class where I display it (**searches_controller.rb**:

```
def index
    @application = Application.search(params[:query])
end
```

and finally the index.html.erb file:

```
<%= form_tag search_startup_path, method: :get do %>
 <p>
  <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query] %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
 </p>
<% end %> 

<hr>
<% @application.each do |f| %>

 <h2><%= f.company.name %> is looking for a <%= f.work_type %></h2>
   <%= image_tag f.company.avatar(:medium), alt:"#{f.company.name.pluralize} logo", height:"100", width:"100" %>
   <p><%= link_to "Visit #{f.company.name.pluralize} website", f.company.website, rel: "nofollow" %></p>
   <p>Company located in: <%= f.company.city %>, <%= f.company.country %></p>
   <p>Required to be on location: <%= f.location %> </p>

<% end %>
```

So viewing the associated company database without elasticsearch works fine. So there is no error there, again I'm just unsure how to enable elasticsearch to view the ass. model

Answer (score 2):

New elastic search library returns only data from elasticsearch and wraps it into `Hashie::Mash` gem. So you working only with `Elasticsearch::Model::Response::Result` class. If you want to work with `ActiveRecord` your index action have to look like this:

```
def index
  @application = Application.search(params[:query]).records
end
```

`records` method returns collection of `ActiveRecord` models, you can find more info on github read me https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails/tree/master/elasticsearch-model#search-results-as-database-records